# How to count apparition of words and sort them

Tags: c++

I encountered this problem, and I decided to ask here for a solution. I receive an input file, which contains words and puncts. I have to sort these words alphabetically, and count the apparition of this word. I solved half of the problem, by excluding all the puncts and putting them in a vector. But, now I encounter problem. I kinda know to sort the words (bubble sort), but I don't know how to combine the sort with the apparition. I would be glad if someone helped me.

For example, If I receive this input: Ana are doua mere, unul verde si unul rosu.

In output I should have : Ana 1 ,are 1 ,doua 1 ,mere 1,rosu 1, si 1 ,unul 2,verde 1.

What I have done until now:

```
ifstream f(input_file_name);
ofstream g(output_file_name);
int nr=0,i,j;
char s[100],new_s[50][100],aux[100],*sterge;
while(!f.eof())
{
    f.get(s,100);
    sterge = strtok(s,",.?!:;");
    while(sterge)
    {
        nr++;
        strcpy(new_s[nr],sterge);
        sterge = strtok(NULL,",.?!:;");
    }
    f.get();
```

s is the char, where I read from the input file; and new_s is the char where I have only the words without any (.;,-.. and so on)

Comment: Please make it easier for us and you to help you by not using single letter variables and indenting your code properly. Thx.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will try to be more clear. It's c++.

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Answer (score 2):

As this is tagged `c++`, I suggest you to use it's functionalities.

For this task, I'd use a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (which will order your words by default), with `std::string` as key (word) and some int to do the counting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss {"ab! ab .ab !?ab ...ab?! 3434 Ab aB AB"};

    std::map<std::string, int> words;
    std::string word;
    while(ss >> word)
    {
        // replace all characters that are not std::isalpha with space
        std::replace_if(word.begin(), word.end(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int,int>(&std::isalpha)), ' ');
        // remove spaces, and check if the word is valid (not all spaces)
        if(word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), std::ptr_fun<int,int>(&std::isspace)), word.end()) != word.begin())
            words[word] ++;
    }

    for(auto & w : words)
        std::cout << w.first << " " << w.second << "\n";
}
```

(just change `stringstream` for your file input)

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86d29d2249f6b30a)

Comment: Yes, but if you have puncts in your input, you have to exclude them. Not sort with them. For example, when it sorts it puts  "mere," not "mere".

Comment: @JohnK allright, I tried with your example input. Can you be more clear with those 'puncts' ? Will always have one, two, .. between words, .. ?

Comment: Consider this input :  "  ab! ab .ab !?ab ...ab?! 3434 Ab         aB     AB "

Comment: As output you have: AB 1 Ab 1 aB 1 ab 5

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct word_delim : std::ctype<char> 
{
  word_delim() : std::ctype<char>( table() ) 
  {
    // nop
  }

  static mask const* table()
  {
    static mask t[table_size/*256*/];
    t[' '] = std::ctype_base::space;
    t['\t'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    t['\r'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    t['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    t['.'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    t[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
    // ...
    return t;
  }
};

int main() 
{
  std::ifstream is( "d:\\temp\\input.txt" );
  if ( ! is )
    return -1;
  is.imbue(std::locale(is.getloc(), new word_delim));

  std::map< std::string, int > m;
  std::string w;
  while ( is >> w )
    m[w]++;

  std::ofstream os( "d:\\temp\\output.txt" );
  if ( ! os )
    return -2;

  for ( const auto e : m )
    os << e.first << ": " << e.second << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If the above solution is too complicated, you could build your own word reading function to take "space" characters into account.

Comment: See the ellipsis in `table()`. A digit is just another "space".

Comment: In my inputfile i only have to remove ,.?!:; . If I add t['?'] = std::ctype_base::space;
  t['!'] = std::ctype_base::space;
  t[':'] = std::ctype_base::space;
  t[';'] = std::ctype_base::space; . It doesn't work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is to vague. What did you do, and what was the expected outcome? It should work. Check your changes. Note that you should add all default spaces (`' ', '\t', etc.`).